# Accentset not working with fraktur

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

The following code works fine

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{accents}

\usepackage[
    cal = cm,
    bb = ams,
    frak = euler,
    scr = euler
]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}

$\accentset{\circ}{\mathfrak{D}}$ % newton

\end{document}
```

But when I put the newton line into another file where `amsfonts` is loaded, and I add all my work I get

```
! Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition.
\reserved@b ->\relax 
                     \ifmmode \else \non@alpherr \mathfrak  \fi \use@mathgro...
l.50 \end{align}

? 
! Emergency stop.
\reserved@b ->\relax 
                     \ifmmode \else \non@alpherr \mathfrak  \fi \use@mathgro...
l.50 \end{align}
```

I think the trouble is with the command `\accentset`.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: please make an example that shows the error, just start with a copy of your document and remove everything that doesn't stop the error appearing, it's hard to debug unseen code.

Comment: What do you mean with *another file*? Do you mean within an included file?

Comment: By the way, LaTeX has `\mathring`. It's impossible to say something until seeing code that produces the error.

Comment: @Sigur Yes, I do `\input{gravity}` and the gravity file contains the newton line.

Comment: `align` is defined by `amsmath`.  `\reserved@a` is also defined by `amsmath`.  so putting together `amsmath` and `accents` is likely to result in conflicts.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I do use `amsmath` in my full document.

Comment: @egreg just for the record, `\mathring` also gives this problem. I will try to produce a mwe.

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton -- and that is why a *non*working example is useful, showing what's in play when the error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `mathalfa`, while perhaps handy for setting different math alphabets, conflicts with `amsfonts` that also defines `\mathfrak` and `\mathbb`.

However `amsfonts` does this definition conditionally:

```
103 \@ifundefined{mathfrak}{%
104     \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{U}{euf}{m}{n}
105     \SetMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{bold}{U}{euf}{b}{n}
106 }{}
107 \@ifundefined{mathbb}{%
108     \DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{AMSb}%
109 }{}
```

so it's safe to load it *after* `mathalfa`. It does nothing, in this case, if you have declared fonts for `\mathfrak` and `\mathbb` with the other package, but it's important if you want to load `amssymb` (which depends on `amsfonts`).

So the correct order would be

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage[
    cal = cm,
    bb = ams,
    frak = euler,
    scr = euler
]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

The error is triggered by `\text{$...$}` in an `align` environment, because this is quite a complex situation, with math nested in math at various levels, with the additional problem of double passing over the material.

Note that you don't need `accents` for a ring accent in math mode, because LaTeX already provides `\mathring`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage[
    cal = cm,
    bb = ams,
    frak = euler,
    scr = euler
]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\text{$S$}
\mathring{\mathfrak{D}}
\accentset{\circ}{\mathfrak{D}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I find the rendering with `\mathring` much better.

Answer (score 0):

When doing the mwe, I found the faulty line.
Thanks to all for your help.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % delete to remove error
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage[
    cal = cm,
    bb = ams,
    frak = euler,
    scr = euler
]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}     

\begin{align}
     \text{  $S$ }
     \accentset{\circ}{ \mathfrak{D} }
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i trust you'll hang in here, to be able to answer when the problem reappears.  the other poor user suffers the same problem and can't find the solution by searching here.